# Cleaner way to extract data based off months into separate data frames in R

Tags: r

I am working with a pretty large data set (~9000 rows, 10 columns), that spans 2005 to 2013 with multiple iterations daily. The data has a date column that I wanted to use to extract each month's values from 2005 to 2013. I was able to do this, however I was trying to figure out a cleaner way to do this. The way I have it right now is:

```
workframe <- workframe %>% filter(workframe$Date >= "2005-06-01") #start from 2005 cycle

jan<-workframe[months(workframe$Date) %in% month.name[1:1],]

feb<-workframe[months(workframe$Date) %in% month.name[2:2],]

mar<-workframe[months(workframe$Date) %in% month.name[3:3],]

apr<-workframe[months(workframe$Date) %in% month.name[4:4],]

may<-workframe[months(workframe$Date) %in% month.name[5:5],]

jun<-workframe[months(workframe$Date) %in% month.name[6:6],]

jul<-workframe[months(workframe$Date) %in% month.name[7:7],]

aug<-workframe[months(workframe$Date) %in% month.name[8:8],]

sep<-workframe[months(workframe$Date) %in% month.name[9:9],]

oct<-workframe[months(workframe$Date) %in% month.name[10:10],]

nov<-workframe[months(workframe$Date) %in% month.name[11:11],]

dec<-workframe[months(workframe$Date) %in% month.name[12:12],]
```

I was thinking about a for loop, but is there a better way to do this?

The columns are:

`Date`        `Name` `Id` `Height` `Width` `mod_date` `POSIXct` `mod_height` `mod_width` `Residual`

Thanks in advance for any suggestions, I really appreciate it.
Regards.

Comment: The reason for the for loop is because I plan also calculating the standardized residuals and RMSE  for each of these months year over year to compare and plot. So there's a lot of copy and pasting going on in areas where I'm guessing there is a more efficient way of going about it.

Comment: Read about lists, try: `mySplitData <- split(workframe[ workframe$Date >= "2005-06-01", ], months( workframe[ workframe$Date >= "2005-06-01",  "Date" ]))`

Comment: Wow, I feel retarded. Thank you! I'll read up more into lists as well. I think I misunderstood how lists work in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *lists* instead, filter on date, then *split* on months:

```
# subset on date
x <- workframe[ workframe$Date >= "2005-06-01", ]

# then split on months
mySplitData <- split(x, months(x$Date))
```